# Entity Framework on delete cascade

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I have problem with deleting related rows in Entity Framework 4.1. I have tables with relations

Book  1<--->* BookFormats

I have set the on delete cascade:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BookFormats]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BookFormats_Book] 
FOREIGN KEY([BookID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Book] ([BookID]) on delete cascade
```

The EDMX property

[image]

Then, I want to remove the all `BokFormats` items related to my `Book` object:

```
 var originalBook = m.db.Book.First(x => x.BookID == bookId);
 originalBook.BookFormats.Clear();
 m.db.SaveChanges();
```

But, I get the error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

I ran out of ideas on how to delete these objects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cascade deletions concept is as follows:

When you delete `Book` from the DB all related `BookFormats` will be deleted for you by SQL Server (please note that it doesn't matter how deletion of `Book` will be initiated via EF or raw SQL). Thus it has nothing to do with your task: "I want to delete all `BookFormats` related to my `Book`". To accomplish it you need something like this:

```
foreach(var m in m.db.BookFormats.Where(f=>f.BookID == bookID))
{
    m.db.BookFormats.Remove(m);
}
m.db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use RemoveRange :

```
m.db.BookFormats.RemoveRange(originalBook.BookFormats);
m.db.SaveChanges();
```

But this is for EF 6.0

Comment: Yep. It is example on RemoveRange. But I will edit the post to not confuse some. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are not deleting the `BookFormats` from the database, but you are removing the relationship, thus orpahning your `BookFormats` and setting the `BookID` column to *NULL*.  The delete cascade you have put on the database says `When I delete the`Book`, then delete all of the`BookFormats`that have a`BookID`equal to mine.`  You are not deleting the book you are deleting the formats from the `Book`.

Instead of `originalBook.BookFormats.Clear()` you should have something like this...

```
List<int> idsToDelete = new List<int>();

foreach (BookFormat bf in originalBook.BookFormats)
{
    idsToDelete.Add(bf.ID);
}

foreach (int id in idsToDelete)
{
    BookFormat format = m.db.BookFormat.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
    if (format != null)
    {
         m.db.DeleteBookFormat(format);
    }
}

m.db.SaveChanges();
```

It should be something along those lines.  I don't have it right in front of me to remember how EF constructs the delete method in the EDMX.

Comment: well then I get the error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: @Tony, check the change to code.  Not the prettiest way, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it in EF 6.1.3 and this should work fine:

```
 var originalBook = m.db.Book.First(x => x.BookID == bookId);
 originalBook.BookFormats.Clear();
 db.Books.Remove(originalBook);
 m.db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use EF6 and this works.

```
        var itemBinding = db.ItemBinding.Where(x => x.BindingToId == id) ;
        foreach (var ib in itemBinding)
        {
            db.Item.Remove(ib.Item);
            db.ItemBinding.Remove(ib);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: EF 7 has not been released. EF 6.1 is the latest stable version.